# My Array inside a foreach loop is not accepting a variable in PHP & Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a Category array that I'm looping through and counting the subcategories that have their Category ID as the ID of the current item in the loop. It is retrieving the county just fine, uynfportunately when adding to the array it adds the value of zero. When echoed out, the values are as they should be, its only when inserting into the array the value becomes a zero.

This is the code I'm working with in PHP. I am using the Laravel framework.

```
 public function index()
{
    $categories = $this->categories->get()->toArray();

    $categories_array = array();
    $stats = array();
 // dd($categories);
    foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
    {

        $subcats_number = sub_categories::whereCategory_id($value['id'])->count();

        $stats = array_add($stats, 'subcategories', $subcats_number);

        echo $subcats_number.'<br/>';
        $listings = classifieds::whereCategory_id($value['id'])->count();

        $stats = array_add($stats, 'listings', $listings);

        $categories_array = array_add($categories_array, $value['name'], $stats);
    }

   dd($categories_array);

  //  return view('admin.categories', compact('categories_array'));
}
```

The result of my dd:

[Dump Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NtRA.png)

Comment: What happen if you declare your `$stats` array into your foreach loop? 
On an other hand, I'm not sure that the use of `array_add()` is appropriate here. I'm going to try an example as an answer...

Comment: Would you look at that! It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `array_add()` helper is appropriate for your function here. As the doc says "The array_add function adds a given key / value pair to the array if the given key doesn't already exist in the array", and I am not sure that this is the proper behavior you need.

I would rather use a simple `array_push()` here:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = $this->categories->get()->toArray();

    $categories_array = array();

    foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
    {
        $subcats_number = sub_categories::whereCategory_id($value['id'])->count();
        $listings = classifieds::whereCategory_id($value['id'])->count();

        $stats = array('subcategories' => $subcats_number,'listings' => $listings);
        array_push($categories_array,$value['name'] => $stats);
    }

   dd($categories_array);
}
```

Otherwise, you should also declare the `$stats` array into your loop if you choose to keep the `array_add()` function...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for help. Will switch to Array push